# how to set the destination folder for wget?

Tags: wget

I am pretty new `wget`. I just need to know how I can set destination folder where downloads are saved.

I believe that is `--directory-prefix`.

Thank you,

Comment: You're correct; it is `--directory-prefix` (or -P). Of course, if wget is doing a recursive copy, it will create more subdirectories under that directory. Look into the `-nH` and `--cut-dirs` options to control that.

Comment: More importantly: what are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 46):

Use `-P` option then specify the destination:

```
wget url -P /path/to/folder
```